# Digital line topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ and partitions

Tags: general-topology, set-partition

Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with the digital line topology, which has as a basis the sets $\{n\}$ for $n$ odd, and $\{n-1,n,n+1\}$ for $n$ even, and consider the partition of $\mathbb{Z}$ created using modulo $10$ arithmetic. The partition gives the mapping:

$$\{\ldots, –30, –20, –10, 0, 10, 20, \ldots\} \to 0$$

$$\{\ldots, –29, –19, –9, 1, 11, 21, \ldots\} \to 1$$

$$\{\ldots, –28, –18, –8, 2, 12, 22, \ldots\} \to 2$$
$$           \cdots$$
$$\{\ldots, –21, –11, –1, 9, 19, 29, \ldots\} \to 9$$

How do I know which sets are open in quotient topology on $\{0,1,2\ldots,9\}$?

Comment: Could you please provide a definition of "digital line topology"? I've never heard of it and a quick search doesn't provide any useful result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some hints/comments.

The digital line topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ has as a basis the sets $\{n\}$ for $n$ odd, and $\{n-1,n,n+1\}$ for $n$ even.

Consider the quotient map $q\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$. Then $U\subseteq\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ is open, iff $q^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{Z}$ in the digital line topology.

Let's understand this property. If $0<n<10$ is odd, and I interpret it as an element in the quotient space, then $q^{-1}(\{n\}) = \{n+10r\ |\ r\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, i.e. the preimage consists of a disjoint collection of odd numbers, which is open.

If $n$ had been even, you see that the preimage would not have been open.

Can the preimage of a set of two numbers $\{n,m\}$, where they are not both odd, ever be open?

What if you consider the preimage $q^{-1}(\{0,1,2\})$? How about $q^{-1}(\{1,2,3\})$?

When is the preimage of three consecutive integers open?

Comment: Ok. So if I am understanding this then the answer to your first question would be no. {0,1,2} would not be open but {1,2,3} would be open. The preimage of 3 consecutive integers is open when it is {n-1,n,n+1} and n is even.

Comment: @bvt5050 yeah. Also remember to think about the preimage of {9,0,1}. Now you just need to patch the argument together and figure out what the open sets in the quotient space all look like.